# Spring 3.0 not finding the applicationcontext.xml

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I'm working on web application that uses a database storage system and I chose to keep the `dataAccess-applicationcontext` seperate from the rest. However when I run the following line of code it says it does not exist.

```
ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("dataAccess-applicationContext.xml", UsageDataDAO.class);
```

I have even moved the xml file to the same directory only to get the same error as posted below.

> nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/foobar/bar/foo/dataAccess-applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Any Idea what is going on here?

Comment: What directory is the file in? What package is the class containing your line of code in?

Comment: I've tried it with the file in the same directory, the directory just above, the WEB-INF, and the very root of the application. None of which works.

Answer (score 1):

This is hard to debug without all of the details, but it has to be one of two issues.

First, the file really isn't in your classpath. This is a web application, so you should consider [how your particular servlet container works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264828/controlling-the-classpath-in-a-servlet) when you're checking the classpath. For example, in a servlet environment, WEB-INF is not in the classpath, but WEB-INF/classes is.

Second, the file is in your classpath, but you're referring to it incorrectly. Based on the information that you provided already, I don't think this is the case, but this possibility can be expanded on later.

Regardless, why are you trying to load a file manually? You should reference the configs in your web.xml. If you provide more details about how you're running your web application, then we can help you with this part. In the meantime, this example might be enough information. It illustrates how to configure the root spring container that's shared by all of the Servlets and Filters in the container (configuring a specific Servlet requires a slightly different approach):

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/config1.xml, /WEB-INF/config2.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

please edit your file name with underscore dataAccess_applicationContext.xml instead dataAccess-applicationContext.xml. And try again.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the classpath*: prefix . "classpath*:dataAccess-application-context.xml" if it is in the root classpath else use "classpath*:/folderName/dataAccess-application-context.xml"

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't help with the error either. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd parameter to:

```
ApplicationContext ac = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("dataAccess-applicationContext.xml", 
        UsageDataDAO.class);
```

Includes **UsageDataDAO.class**. According to the spring [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html#ClassPathXmlApplicationContext%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) for this class, this is requesting the context search start in **com/foobar/bar/foo/**.

Instead put **dataAccess-applicationContext.xml** in **WEB-INF/classes** and try:

```
ApplicationContext ac = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("dataAccess-applicationContext.xml");
UsageDataDAO myDao = (UsageDataDAO) ac.getBean("MyDaoBeanName");
```