# Servlet web.xml filter -- Class not found exception

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I am having a problem setting up the filter - 
the filter I have defined in web.xml looks like this

```
  <filter>
   <filter-name>Log</filter-name>
   <filter-class>test.log</filter-class> 
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>Log</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
```

But I am getting the following error -

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter Log
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.log
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1711)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1556)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:532)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:514)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I have the class defined but for some reason I am getting the Classnotfoundexcetion. Can someone help me out?

EDIT ---

I have a package called test and a class called log.

```
             package test;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.servlet.*;
    import javax.servlet.http.*;
    import java.util.*;

    // Implements Filter class
     public class log implements Filter  {
         public void  init(FilterConfig config) {

          }
         public void  doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
             ServletResponse response,
             FilterChain chain) 
             throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {

  // Get the IP address of client machine.   
  String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();

  // Log the IP address and current timestamp.
  System.out.println("IP "+ ipAddress + ", Time "
                                   + new Date().toString());

  // Pass request back down the filter chain
  chain.doFilter(request,response);
  }
   public void destroy( ){
      /* Called before the Filter instance is removed 
      from service by the web container*/
  }
 }
```

Thank You,

Comment: do you have a class `log` in a package named `test`?

Comment: Is it deployed? Is it packaged correctly? FWIW, you should probably follow Java naming conventions, which state class names should begin with an upper-case letter.

Comment: Is the class in your war/WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: It could also be in `WEB-INF/classes/test`

Comment: I have the class in my Java Resources ..

Comment: obviously the class file of your filter is not on the class path. From the stack trace one can see that you are starting a Tomcat servlet container. The phrase "in my Java Resources" points to Eclipse. Am I right? There are many ways to have missing files on the classpath of a Eclipse Dynamic Web Project. Sometimes if everything seams to be right and it is still not working cleaning/republishing helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The filter-class parameter needs to be a Java class that should implement the Filter interface.  Can you check if that's the case with you?

Check this example for guidance:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-java-servlet-filter-example-using-eclipse-apache-tomcat/

From the above link:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LogFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        net.viralpatel.servlet.filters.LogFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>test-param</param-name>
        <param-value>This parameter is for testing.</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LogFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>



public class LogFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {...
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

Funny enough, this same issue just happened to me today while it was working on yesterday. After investigation showing nothing was wrong, I concluded this was an eclipse environment issue:

- Stop the tomcat server
- Cleaned the project (Project->Clean...)
- Refresh the whole project (right click on project name -> Refresh)
- Start the server on again.

Issue gone!

Comment: Had the same problem, but I cleaned my project purposely. Thanks for your answer, because I don't know how long it would take me to find 'Refresh' option ;)

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution, try putting your `log.class` file into this directory:

```
tomcat/webapps/[your app name]/WEB-INF/classes/test
```

Create that directory if it doesn't exist.

---

**How to find your .class file:**

Most times, the default setting for Eclipse will compile your source file (`.java`) into a `.class` file whenever you save it, otherwise you may have to press CTRL-B (build) to force it compile into a `.class` file.

Once that is done you will be able to find the `log.class` file in your Eclipse workspace at: `[your workspace name]/[your eclipse project name]/bin/test/`

The workspace directory location is usually visible right when you start eclipse. For Windows 7 I think it defaults to the `Users` directory, WinXP and 2000 it defaults to the user's `Documents and Settings` folder.

Alternately:

You should have a "Package Explorer" view on the left side of your Eclipse window. It will contain a `log.java` leaf in the package tree. If you right-click that leaf and then click on `Show In` > `Navigator` that will open the actual file structure in the "Navigator" view.

There should be a `bin` node visible in that view. Inside that you should find a `test` node and then inside that you will see `log.class`. You can right-click on it to copy it and then simply navigate to the directory I gave at the top and paste it in.

All should be well.

Comment: Hi this might be stupid question, but when I am running the project on Eclipse how do I grad the .class file?

Comment: @Fox Added more data on locating the `.class` file.

Answer (score 0):

This can be something wrong in the source code of the related class.

Recently I happened to see the same problem.
After a real long time hard investigation, I found that the exception is encoded in the class:

```
$ jad BaseController.class 
Parsing BaseController.class...The class file version is 51.0 (only 45.3, 46.0 and 47.0 are supported)
 Generating BaseController.jad
$ cat BaseController.jad 
// Decompiled by Jad v1.5.8e. Copyright 2001 Pavel Kouznetsov.
// Jad home page: http://www.geocities.com/kpdus/jad.html
...
import HttpServletRequest;
import HttpServletResponse;
import HttpSession;
...
public class BaseController
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        throw new Error("Unresolved compilation problems: \n\tThe import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest cannot be resolved\n\tThe import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse cannot be resolved\n\tThe import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession cannot be resolved\n\tHttpSession cannot be resolved to a type\n\tHttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type\n\tHttpSession cannot be resolved to a type\n\tHttpSession cannot be resolved to a type\n\tHttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type\n\tHttpServletRequest cannot be resolved to a type\n\tHttpServletResponse cannot be resolved to a type\n");
    }
...
```

So, after recompile the source with necessary libs, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Had the problem once, finally right click on project -> **Build project** helped.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing that you don't have it copied correctly be included in the servlet classpath.

See here for what makes up the servlet classpath:

[Controlling the classpath in a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264828/controlling-the-classpath-in-a-servlet)

Comment: What do I have to copy in the classpath?

Comment: When executing your code in the scope of a servlet, it needs to be in one of a few particular locations.  It depends on the servlet container, and how you're packaging your classes, but the easiest way to fix this is to just grab the .class and put it in /WEB-INF/classes/test