# Error instead of warn on logback Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath

Tags: java, runtime-error, classpath, logback

To share logback configuration between multiple projects we embed our logback.xml file within a common jar. e.g. **mylogger.jar**. Projects depend upon this jar for logging hence it's always on the classpath. This means the logback.xml will be found as documented at

https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#auto_configuration

However if another jar, e.g. **otherlib.jar**, also embeds a logback.xml file we'll see a warning

```
09:27:03,122 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
09:27:03,122 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
09:27:03,122 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/WEB-INF/lib/mylogger.jar/logback.xml]
09:27:03,123 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
09:27:03,123 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/WEB-INF/lib/mylogger.jar/logback.xml]
09:27:03,123 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/WEB-INF/lib/otherlib.jar/logback.xml]
```

Worse sometimes it does not pick the correct logback.xml as this behavior is non-deterministic according to [Controlling the classpath in a servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/264828/controlling-the-classpath-in-a-servlet).

Is there any mechanism to force the warning to fail a build? This'll alert us to the above scenario whereas a warning can be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During initialisation Logback emits `Status` events to describe what's happening. These ...

```
09:27:03,123 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
09:27:03,123 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/WEB-INF/lib/mylogger.jar/logback.xml]
09:27:03,123 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/WEB-INF/lib/otherlib.jar/logback.xml]
```

... are log statements for some of the `Status` events. These `Status` events are emitted by Logback's `ContextInitializer` ...

```
if (urlSet != null && urlSet.size() > 1) {
    sm.add(new WarnStatus("Resource [" + resourceName + "] occurs multiple times on the classpath.", loggerContext));
    for (URL url : urlSet) {
        sm.add(new WarnStatus("Resource [" + resourceName + "] occurs at [" + url.toString() + "]", loggerContext));
    }
}
```

You're likely seeing those events logged because you have configured Logback with `<configuration debug="true">`. Using `debug=true` is equivalent to installing an `OnConsoleStatusListener`.

You could register a custom `StatusListener` which reacts to these `Status` events differently. Given that you want to "force the warning to fail a build" then you could throw an exception when your `StatusListener` encounters the "Resource ... occurs multiple times on the classpath." event.

Here's an (untested) example:

```
import ch.qos.logback.core.status.Status;
import ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusListener;

public class StrictConfigurationWarningStatusListener implements StatusListener {
    @Override
    public void addStatusEvent(Status status) {
        if (status.getEffectiveLevel() == Status.WARN) {
            // you might want to consider how best to evaluate whether this is the message you are interested in
            // this approach is bound to a string and hence will no longer work if Logback changes this message
            if (status.getMessage().endsWith("occurs multiple times on the classpath.")) {
                throw new LogbackException(status.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can register your listener in `logback.xml` as follows:

```
<statusListener class="some.package.StrictConfigurationWarningStatusListener" />
```

With the above registration and listener in place you'll be able to intercept the "Resource ... occurs multiple times on the classpath." events and provide your own action/response to them.

Answer (score 0):

### My use case: multiple `logback-test.xml` files on the class path when running tests

I looked at the approach suggested by @glytching in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51891708/227779, but there were two problems with it:

1. Some events are created (in my particular use case) *before* Logback instantiates my `statusListener`. In my case, this was the case with the particular events we wanted to react to here.
2. Throwing exceptions from a status listener doesn't really work (it will not be propagated to the calling code but caught and handled by Logback itself).

Based on the `ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnPrintStreamStatusListenerBase` class in Logback, I figured out how to solve issue 1.

To solve issue 2, I added a static `EVENTS` field that I populate, and then an `ensureEventsIsEmpty` method in the listener. I can then call it from a static initializer (in a unit test class in my case) like this:

```java
public class SomeTestClass {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger( SomeTestClass.class );

    static {
        StrictConfigurationWarningStatusListener.ensureNoEventsReceived();
    }

    // ...test methods goes here.
}
```

#### Adjusted `StrictConfigurationWarningStatusListener` implementation

```
package some.package;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.ContextAwareBase;
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.LifeCycle;
import ch.qos.logback.core.status.Status;
import ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusListener;
import ch.qos.logback.core.status.StatusManager;

public class StrictConfigurationWarningStatusListener extends ContextAwareBase implements StatusListener, LifeCycle {
    private static final List<String> EVENTS = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    private boolean isStarted = false;

    public static void ensureNoEventsReceived() {
        if ( !EVENTS.isEmpty() ) {
            for ( String event : EVENTS ) {
                System.err.println( event );
            }

            throw new IllegalStateException( "Multiple logback-test.xml files found on the classpath." );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addStatusEvent( Status status ) {
        if ( !isStarted ) {
            // Events being posted at this stage will be retrieved from the StatusManager in the
            // retrospectivelyHandleEvents() method.
            return;
        }

        handleEvent( status );
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        isStarted = true;

        retrospectivelyHandleEvents();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        isStarted = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isStarted() {
        return isStarted;
    }

    private void handleEvent( Status status ) {
        if ( status.getEffectiveLevel() == Status.WARN ) {
            if ( status.getOrigin() instanceof LoggerContext &&
                    ( status.getMessage().contains( "occurs multiple times" ) ||
                            status.getMessage().contains( "occurs at" ) ) ) {

                EVENTS.add( status.getMessage() );
            }
        }
    }

    private void retrospectivelyHandleEvents() {
        StatusManager statusManager = context.getStatusManager();
        List<Status> statusList = statusManager.getCopyOfStatusList();

        for ( Status status : statusList ) {
            handleEvent( status );
        }
    }
}
```